# How to find releases on some project on Github

Tags: github

Following page [page](https://jamesbowley.co.uk/buildcompile-opencv-v3-3-on-windows-with-cuda-8-0-and-intel-mkltbb/#gui) points to Github's [page](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/releases/tag/3.3.0) where pre-build binaries are contained. If I have not found first mentioned page first then I would have not an idea that such page (with pre-build binaries) exists on Github. Is it usual to put some pre-build binaries under releases on GitHub (I've seen it also other times e.g. with [gns3](https://github.com/GNS3/gns3-gui/releases))? Is there any link on project's Github page which will point me to releases (maybe I can add `releases` to corresponding URL but I guess there must be some link which points to it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "release" pages is available on any GitHub project. You can access it quickly using the link on top of project (between branches and contributors):

[image: opencv gh page]

GitHub release page is computed from Git repository tags. The maintainer of the project is free to use it or not, but it's a common practice to transform a git tag into a release, attaching a description (changelog, release note, etc) and/or some files (pre-build packages, setups, DMGs, etc.)

GitHub team wrote [a blog post](https://github.com/blog/1547-release-your-software) a few years ago to explain this feature.